# Can a detection mechanism like EURion be used on other documents than banknotes to protect them?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, copyright, copy-protection

The [EURion Constellation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EURion_constellation) is a pattern of **symbols** that make it difficult to scan or photograph banknotes [and import it into Photoshop](https://hyperallergic.com/195922/what-happens-when-you-try-to-photoshop-money/).

[image]

*From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EURion_constellation)*

I am interested in understanding how this system works, and how single users could design patterns of symbols that **Photoshop** would not be able to import.

From what I have gathered online, the pattern itself is detected by **Photoshop**, so I am assuming that a user couldn't design their own pattern to protect their work individually.

[image]

But is there a way to reuse the already existing pattern in a graphical document to block a user from opening an image that contains it?

<sub>***Disclaimer***: I am not asking to reveal trade secrets regarding the making of money and I am not asking about counterfeiting techniques. I am asking about using a technology to do more copy protection than it was designed to do.</sub>

Comment: Except photoshop does not react to EURion but a digimark watermark

Comment: I'm confused I thought the name of this digital watermark was "EURion constellation". The first two sentences in the wikipedia article say that.

Comment: The constellation has no name as far as we know it its called "Omron anti-photocopying feature" but the warning is supposedly based on digimark which is a different thing. In reality we dont know. In any case i can still edit the banknote just not in PS. Which isn't much of a impediment

Comment: Who's "we"?  The point of this question is to get to the bottom of things... Here's [Digimarc](https://www.digimarc.com/solutions/retail-brand/brand-protection#options) (with a C)'s page on this.

Comment: "we" is all of the poeople not in the know

Comment: Anyway you can use digimarc on your image in photoshop all you need to do is to register it

Comment: Ok so maybe something similar than what digimarc did? Maybe there are ways to natively protect content within photoshop?

Comment: Thats what i said digimarc is available from filter > Digimarc But its not free to use